# Should I use modal or page if there are multiple of steps?

Tags: modal

I was wondering whether to make it a modal or a page.

So the process is this:

1. Enter full name and birthdate
   [image]
2. Answer security questions
   [image]
3. Upload an ID
   [image]

After uploading an ID, there are 2 pages that still needs to be filled out.

Comment: If you do use a modal, consider what will happen if the user accidentally clicks out and closes it. Will they lose all their progress if they are near the end of filling it out?

Answer (score 5):

I would use a page layout with multiple pages if you want to differentiate between each step of the registration process.

I prefer this way because having many user interactions in a modal is not optimal and really breaks the flow of how the user interacts with your app.

Answer (score 1):

The choice on the debate between Modal vs Fullpage UI typically depends on,

> the point of user journey from where the user lands.
>
> type of information required for the user.

Considering your case, its best to go for a modal carousel, as the user would be fully focused on entering the information and wont lose his focus. This is required as the information he will be entering is crucial.

Still if the form is too long you can give him a full page redirect on a new tab, but not on the same page with other information being displayed that can take his attention.

Answer (score 0):

[Modal Carousel](https://codepen.io/krnlde/pen/pGijB) could be an option, there are several examples on the internet.

[image: Modal Carousel]

Comment: I'm facing similar issue here. Could you provide a realistic example of this in action?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Modals are good for short flows that are connected to the main screen (think: changing personal data, or adding an item to an existing page). Modals have the added benefit as acting as a sort of 'side-step', meaning users can immediately return to the main screen.

If you need a user to really focus on a new and different process, then it's better to use a page. You'll have more screen-estate.

Modals used to be considered a bad practise for multi-screen flows, this is changing though. They're getting more user friendly and are nowadays considered a viable alternative, especially if paired with a [stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).